# DataFrame: add column whose values are the quantile number/rank of an existing column?

Tags: python, pandas, ranking-functions

I have a DataFrame with some columns. I'd like to add a new column where each row value is the quantile rank of one existing column.

I can use DataFrame.rank to rank a column, but then I don't know how to get the quantile number of this ranked value and to add this quantile number as a new colunm.

Example: if this is my DataFrame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 1], [2, 10], [3, 100], [4, 100]]), columns=['a', 'b'])

   a    b
0  1    1
1  2   10
2  3  100
3  4  100
```

and I'd like to know the quantile number (using 2 quantiles) of column b. I'd expect this result:

```
   a    b  quantile
0  1    1    1
1  2   10    1
2  3  100    2
3  4  100    2
```

Comment: I think you want DataFrame.[quantile](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) with q=[0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]... Then you should be able to [rank](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) on that column

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, posting comment above as answer below.

Comment: I am trying to apply your suggestion but It seems I cannot do it

Comment: It looks like getting the resulting dataframe from quantile back into the original dataframe requires a few extra operations... Working on an edit

Comment: New edit with example code... how does it work for you?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I [discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442991/python-pandas-create-new-bin-bucket-variable-with-pd-qcut) it is quite easy:

```
df['quantile'] = pd.qcut(df['b'], 2, labels=False)

   a    b  quantile
0  1    1         0
1  2   10         0
2  3  100         1
3  4  100         1
```

Interesting to know "[difference between pandas.qcut and pandas.cut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211923/what-is-the-difference-between-pandas-qcut-and-pandas-cut)"

Comment: This generally throws a `SettingWithCopyWarning`, at least in 0.16.1 (which I'm still using).

Comment: @feetweet, thanks for reporting the issue with old pandas version (<= 0.16.1) and for the alternative solution. Anyway for versions >= 0.18 it works without any warning.

Comment: to avoid `SettingWithCopyWarning`, use `df.loc[:, "quantile"] = ...`

Answer (score 2):

`df['quantile'] = pd.qcut(df['b'], 2, labels=False)`
seems to tend to throw a `SettingWithCopyWarning`.

The only *general* way I have found of doing this without complaints is like:

```
quantiles = pd.qcut(df['b'], 2, labels=False)
df = df.assign(quantile=quantiles.values)
```

This will assign the quantile rank values as a new `DataFrame` column `df['quantile']`.

[A solution for a more generalized case, in which one wants to partition the cut by multiple columns, is given here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19403133/2662901).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [DataFrame.quantile](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) with q=[0.25, 0.5, 0.75] on the existing column to produce a quartile column.

Then, you can [DataFrame.rank](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) on that quartile column.

See below for an example of adding a quartile column:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'one' : pd.Series([40., 45., 50., 55, 60, 65], index=['val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', 'val6'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

quantile_frame = df.quantile(q=[0.25, 0.5, 0.75])
quantile_ranks = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if (row['one'] <= quantile_frame.ix[0.25]['one']):
        quantile_ranks.append(1)
    elif (row['one'] > quantile_frame.ix[0.25]['one'] and row['one'] <= quantile_frame.ix[0.5]['one']):
        quantile_ranks.append(2)
    elif (row['one'] > quantile_frame.ix[0.5]['one'] and row['one'] <= quantile_frame.ix[0.75]['one']):
        quantile_ranks.append(3)
    else:
        quantile_ranks.append(4)

df['quartile'] = quantile_ranks
```

Note: There's probably a more idiomatic way to accomplish this with Pandas... but it's beyond me

Answer (score 0):

```
df.sort_values(['b'],inplace = True)
df.reset_index(inplace = True,drop = True)
df.reset_index(inplace = True)
df.rename(columns = {'index':'row_num'},inplace = True)
df['quantile'] = df['row_num'].apply(lambda x: math.ceil(10*(x+1)/df.shape[0]))
```

I used to use this, but I guess I can use quantile