# Create a column while this new column is a qcut

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have to use qcut with a column called "PriceEuro", the combination of qcut and "PriceEuro" should be in another column that it must be created. The new column is called "Price_Category". The column "Price_Category" should contain one of these three labels: low, medium or high.

I checked here in stackoverflow and I found this:

[Assignment of qcut as new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959722/assignment-of-qcut-as-new-column)

After reading the previous link I did the following thing:

```
import pandas as pd

new_labels = ['low','medium','high']

new_column = pd.qcut(df_csv3.rank(method='first')['PriceEuro'], q=5, labels=new_labels, duplicates='drop')

df_csv3 = df_csv3.assign(Price_Category=new_column.values)
```

But, once I run it i get the following ValueError:

> first not supported for non-numeric data

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20158597/how-to-qcut-with-non-unique-bin-edges) might help.

Comment: I put this: 
import pandas as pd

new_labels = ['low','medium','high']

new_column = pd.qcut(df_csv3.rank(method='first')['PriceEuro'], q=5, labels=new_labels, duplicates='drop')

df_csv3 = df_csv3.assign(Price_Category=new_column.values)

And I get:
ValueError: first not supported for non-numeric data